# How to pull a blob from SQL and show as response from Ajax request

Tags: sql, ajax, blob

I am sending an AJAX request to an SQL Server and I should receive a bmp file from the blob field.
How am I going to display this at the end of the request?

So far I tried to put the response to the src attribute of an image.
But this does not work.

I am working with IE8.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX expects a text response, not binary. You'd need to BASE-64 encode the response (on the server) and feed it back in to your image's SRC.

See: http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

**EDIT:** Alternately you can make call for the binary data directly, just output the image tag in a format like this:

```
<img src="getImage.php?imageID=xxxxxx">
```

What happens in "getImage" is it sends out a MIME header for and image, then streams out the binary.

Something [like this](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Display_an_image_stored_in_a_database__PHP_-16637.html).

Comment: I think that the response is the picture itself. When I send direct link to the server and open the response as new tab, then it shows the picture. Any idea how to open this in an innerHTML?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8889/ex?sql=SELECT+Image+FROM+Persons+WHERE+Number+Like+%27%2501%27<br> this displays the image.<br>
But how do I open this with AJAX?

Comment: I will open a new question, as the problem seems to have changed. If it turns out that your answer was the right clue, I just did not get it, I will tag you as correct later. Thanks